# SFMC: Query Subscribers with EmailName NOT LIKE but also include subscribers who have never received an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I have created a Query which will query for subscribers from a certain list who have not received an email which its name contains "newsletter_"

This is working perfect

```
SELECT l.[EmailAddress], e.[First_name]
FROM _Job j with (nolock)
INNER JOIN _Sent s with (nolock)
ON j.JobID = s.JobID
INNER JOIN _ListSubscribers l with (nolock)
ON l.subscriberID = s.subscriberID
INNER JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute e with (nolock)
ON l.subscriberID = e._subscriberID
WHERE s.EventDate < GetDate()
AND e.Segment = 'Customer'
AND j.EmailName NOT LIKE 'newsletter_%'
AND l.ListID = 919445
```

the problem is, is this is not bringing back subscribers who have never received and email at all as they are not in the _sent / _job does anyone know how i am able to add subscribers to this query who have never received an email

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have set the condition to j.EmailAddress NOT LIKE 'newsletter_%'. Doesnt this exclude them?

Comment: j.EmailName NOT LIKE 'newsletter_%' does not exclude them nope, as it cant find the subscribers in _job or _sent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you make a separate query using a NOT EXISTS clause and then merge the results?

```
SELECT l.[Email_Address], e.[First_name]
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM _Sent 
  WHERE _Sent.[Email_Address] = _ListSubscribers.[Email_Address]
)
```

Comment: ill give this ago and see if this works on its own

Comment: the above working, thank you

SELECT l.[EmailAddress], e.[First_name]
FROM _ListSubscribers l with (nolock)
INNER JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute e with (nolock)
ON l.subscriberID = e._subscriberID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM _Sent WHERE _Sent.[subscriberID] = l.[subscriberID])

Comment: thank you now i just need to figure out how to combine the two